# Concept if initializing a class in the the delcaration itself

Tags: c++, class, initialization

Can someone who knows c++ explain a concept to me, please?
when you use the initialization of a class, in this example "Society", in the style:

```
Society(const long int np=0, const long int ni=0):
num_people(np),
num_immunized(ni)
```

When I use the constructor in main(), doing:
 `Society(1000, 100);`
how will these parameters change to 1000 and 100 if I'm seting them to 0 them in the declaration?
are they modified back(to 1000 and 100) when I call the initializations of the attributes after `Society(const long int np=0, const long int ni=0)` `(num_people(np),num_immunized(ni))` ?
but how  if I setted them to 0 just before ?

Comment: The equal signs in the parameters of the constructor(`np=0`, `ni=0`) are the default values that apply if you do not provide the arguments, eg `Society s;` or `Society s{20L};`.

Comment: You don't have to decide which one is the best, @AdrianMole -- just pick one, then add the other one as another dupe. Two dupes are always better than one.

Comment: I think the first answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374065/one-question-about-default-value-in-c -- would make this a suitable dupe.

Comment: @Sam Thanks - done! (I'll have to keep waiting for my chance to get a 1000+ upvote canonical. )‎